Upload a source file with information for git-blame
I have a source file that I want to upload into Git.  It is new to the Git repo, but has author information for each line that was tracked in the repo (not Git) that it came from.
Is there a way to upload this file into Git so that this line author information is preserved and is reported by git-blame?

If there is history, it can be migrated to git. What version control system are you using currently?

@iCodeSometime The code is in Cyborg Scripting Language and the history is being provided by Accero Cyborg itself.
The export adds a three character code to the end of each line indicating the author.

You would have to recreate the history as a series of commits.  Do you have that level of information?

If you only have the author and not the remaining commit history, you could append lines until EOF or the author changes, commit with --author, and repeat. History would be nonsense, but blame will work
